# JavaFX loader location not set -Plugin Development

Tags: java, plugins, javafx, eclipse-plugin

As part of a plugin i am creating I am using JavaFX with SceneBuilder to create a GUI.  However, when I use the budle.getResource("SymbolTable.fxml") and load the file I get an error "Location is not set" or else with some changing "Could not load src/.../SymbolTable.fxml".

When I place this fxml file into my resource directory the loader works fine but I need to have the fxml file in the package structure to allow for setting a controller class.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    try { 
        this.primaryStage = stage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Common Symbol Table");
        // Load person overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(bundle.getResource("SymbolTable.fxml"));
        AnchorPane symbolAnchor = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

       // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(symbolAnchor);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        //SymbolTableController controller = loader.getController();
        //controller.setMainApp(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Even when adding the package to the class path the same error occurs.  Is it something to do with the path?

Its strange as it loads the fxml fine when it is placed in the res/ directory.

Here is my classpath:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
.,\
icons/,\
lib/sphinx4-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,\
lib/sphinx4-data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,\
lib/opencv-300.jar,\
res/,\
lib/org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_1.1.0.201411050807.jar
jars.compile.order = .
```

Comment: I've never done any plugin development, but it just seems wrong that it's looking in `src`: source directories are generally not available at runtime. Where is the deployed FXML file, relative to the `bin` folder: that's the path you want to be searching for it?

Comment: I just slapped my head reading your comment.  I placed the src package in the class path rather than the bin.  thanks man lol.